Is there a way to convert assets based on a ScriptableObject to another ScriptableObject type?
Is there a reasonably practical way to convert assets based on a ScriptableObject to another ScriptableObject type (that are not part of the same OOP hierarchy) without breaking references to the asset? I don't even care if the serializable fields get reset or lost - I just want to avoid breaking a lot of things that already depend on referencing existing assets.
